# Meteorjs configure phantomjs for deploy to meteor.com

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

I have installed phantomjs with the binaries w home brew

```
brew update && brew install phantomjs
```

I have installed it with npm and also installed it w `mrt add phantomjs``

Then I have installed spiderable package

When I visit my page on localhost with /?_scaped_fragment=

I get the correct html code of my app

But when I deploy the app ( I sue the default meteor servers for deploy) when I visit mysite/?_scaped_fragment=

I get empty code, no html really, so what Im missing ? I also have uninstalled fastrender and reinstalled the packages.

Answer (score 2):

By default Meteor deploy hosting already has phantomjs installed. (If you want to deploy to meteor.com via `meteor deploy`).

All you have to do is install `spiderable`, not phantomjs. The phantomjs package you installed via `mrt` is not necessary. Nor is phantomjs via brew

```
meteor add spiderable
meteor deploy yoursite.meteor.com
```

Then visit your site.meteor.com/?_scaped_fragment=